# Request pull down of a Picasa album attached to my name in searches

Tags: google-search, privacy, picasa-web-albums

Using Google I found a Picasa album of mine of a mission trip to Bolivia. I never gave permission to put it out there for everyone. Or at least I don't remember doing so.

How do I take it offline and remove the album from showing up in a Google search connected under my name?

Answer (score 2):

1. Login to [PicasaWeb](https://picasaweb.google.com/)
2. Go to **MyPhotos**
3. Go to the respective album
4. Click on **Actions** from the menu above the photos
   [image]
5. Click on **Album properties**
6. In the opened window, set **Visibility** to **Only you**
7. Click **Save**

Answer (score 1):

If you log in [PicasaWeb](http://picasaweb.google.com), you should be able to edit your album and change it's visibility to "Only you". It should prevent it from being indexed, or even being seen by anyone.